How can I process a form in astro. How can I process it without using the DOM?
This is the form made in astro file:
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";

<Layout title="Iniciar Sesión">

    <section>
        <form action="/services/submit" class="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required>
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </section>

</Layout>


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74934690/build-form-submission-handler-using-api-route-in-astro-js-framework/75517574#75517574 may be helpful.

Does this answer your question? Build form submission handler using API Route in Astro JS framework
